# Trying to compile MobileSubstrate addon - Undefined symbol

Tags: iphone, objective-c, gcc, compiler-construction, makefile

I went through [this tutorial](http://iphonesdkdev.blogspot.com/2009/10/how-to-compile-mobilesubstrate.html) to create a MobileSubstrate addon. I could compile the [example hook](http://apiexplorer.googlecode.com/files/ExampleHook.zip) without errors.

But as soon as I add

```
#import <SpringBoard/SBAwayController.h>
```

in `ExampleHookProtocol.h` and

```
SBAwayController *awayController = [SBAwayController sharedAwayController];
```

in `ExampleHookLibrary.mm` (as the first line of the `__$ExampleHook_AppIcon_Launch` function) I get the following error message when attempting to `make` (triggered by the latter change):

```
Undefined symbols:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SBAwayController", referenced from:
    __objc_classrefs__DATA@0 in ExampleHookLibrary.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [ExampleHook.dylib] Error 1.
```

The header file for SBAwayController is located in `/var/toolchain/sys30/usr/include/SpringBoard`, just like `SBApplicationIcon.h`, which is used by the ExampleHook.

I'm compiling on my iPod touch 2G.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance,

Eric

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since there is nothing to link to when you compile, you need to get the class at runtime, so add

```
Class $SBAwayController = objc_getClass("SBAwayController");
```

in the initializer, and change

```
SBAwayController *awayController = [SBAwayController sharedAwayController];
```

to

```
SBAwayController *awayController = [$SBAwayController sharedAwayController];
```

Comment: I know that this is a *very* old question, but I'd have the possible use of the `%c` Logos directive documented here.

Comment: This has literaly opend my eyes to the world of tweaking the lockascreen :D

Answer (score 1):

You can also use:

```
SBAwayController *awayController = [objc_getClass("SBAwayController") sharedAwayController];
```